# preventDefault() not working on production environment

Tags: angularjs, preventdefault

I want to prevent default click action on submit button:

I have a haml form with this button:

```
= f.submit 'Publish', "ng-click" => "submit($event)"
```

a controller:

```
$scope.submit = function(event) {
    if(some_condition) {
      event.preventDefault(); //This is working on development. But not working on production environment.
      //show modal with a message
    }
  }
};
```

I don't want to ask if form it's not valid. "some_condition" It's not related with validations.

Question:

**What am I possibly doing wrong o production env?**

**or what is the right path to take to solve this?** (I'm new with angular)

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.0rc1 (dev and production)

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(event)?

Comment: jQuery.Event {type: "click", timeStamp: 1380672950849, jQuery11000606855190359056: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: ""…}

Comment: Does your production environment have a working copy of jQuery too? iirc event.preventDefault() is a jQuery method.

Comment: v2.0.3 (dev and production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `ng-submit` on the form instead of `ng-click` on the submit button. As the documentation tells: "Enables binding angular expressions to onsubmit events. Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page) but only if the form does not contain an action attribute."

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSubmit

Comment: It would still be nice to know why the preventDefault() in the ng-click wouldn't work for them.